# Is + another expression

Tags: sentence-meaning, grammaticality

1-All you need is do your homework .

2-All you need is to do your homework .

3-All you need is that do your homework .

Are all of these sentences grammatically correct and do they mean the same thing ?

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: The most natural way of expressing the sentiment isn't any of those sentences. I'd say it should be something closer to: *All you need* ***to do*** *is your homework.*

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that the intent of the sentence here is to basically to tell someone to do their homework (presumably as a prerequisite or condition for something else) e.g. someone is asking "Is there anything I have to do tonight?" and this is a response.

> 1-All you need is do your homework.

As it stands this is not grammatically correct and doesn't work.

> 2-All you need is to do your homework.

**Correct!**

> 3-All you need is that do your homework.

As it stands this is not grammatically correct and doesn't work.

Comment: But sometimes I see some sentences similiar to the first one for example : "All you gotta do is say yes."

Comment: @TalhaÖzden the key difference there is "gotta" which is an informal contraction of either "have got a" or "have got to", in this case it's the latter so reads as "All you have got to do is say yes" but since "got" should not be used to refer to actions (as opposed to objects) is more properly written as "All you have to do is say yes" and which is how it would be understood.

Comment: Okey thank you but why we cant use "to" after the "is" in this case ? "All you have to do is to say yes". It sounds so wrong to me but what is the grammatical explanation?

Comment: @TalhaÖzden when "to" is being used as an infinitive - "to [verb]" only [certain verbs](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/verb-patterns/verb-patterns-verb-infinitive-or-verb-ing#verb-patterns-verb-infinitive-or-verb-ing__4) can be followed by a to-inifinitive

Comment: I know that rule :) but in here we are using "to + verb" after the "is" not right after these certain verbs.+Sorry if I am making this so annoying.

Comment: @TalhaÖzden In the sentence in your question (#2 that is) then it parses because they are distinct clauses. Ideally there would be either a colon ":" or a semi-colon ";" to indicate that the "All you need is" and "to do your homework" are connected but separate clauses in the sentence.